# Setting up the visibility of an Image View depending on Shared Preferences

Tags: java, android, uiimageview, sharedpreferences, visibility

I Programm a Quiz App. I already set up that if the highscore is over 10, an ImageView will be shown permanently. That works very fine also on restart of the app, the only problem is  that if the user reachs a highscore of for example 11 and directly later on the beginning of the quiz answers correctly and then false, the ImageView disappears. The shared preference is in the Main Activity (Quiz activity) and will be calles in Menu2 (second Activity).

Quiz Activity java:

```
       @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);


    //Randromizes the row of the questions
    QuestionLibrary q = new QuestionLibrary();
    System.out.printf("Question:0 Choice:(%s, %s, %s) Answer:%s%n",
            q.getChoice1(0), q.getChoice2(0), q.getChoice3(0), q.getCorrectAnswer(0));
    q.shuffle();
    System.out.printf("Question:0 Choice:(%s, %s, %s) Answer:%s%n",
            q.getChoice1(0), q.getChoice2(0), q.getChoice3(0), q.getCorrectAnswer(0));
    mQuestionLibrary.shuffle();
    //End randomizer

    //We need this for the NAVIGATION DRAWER
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.nav_action);

    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);

    mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);
    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
    mToggle.syncState();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); //Able to see the Navigation Burger "Button"


    NavigationView mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nv1);
    mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem){
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
                case(R.id.nav_stats): //If nav stats selected Activity 2 will show up
                    Intent accountActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Menu2.class);
                    startActivity(accountActivity);
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

        //Initialise

        mScoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score_score);
        mQuestionView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
        mButtonChoice1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choice1);
        mButtonChoice2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choice2);
        mButtonChoice3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choice3);


        updateQuestion(); //New question appears

        //Start of Button Listener1 -> if true, next question appears +score +1[] Else menu 2 will show
        mButtonChoice1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //My logic for Button goes in here

                if (mButtonChoice1.getText() == mAnswer) {
                    mScore = mScore + 1;
                    updateScore(mScore);
                    updateQuestion();



                    //This line of code is optional...
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Wrong... Try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, Menu2.class);
                    intent.putExtra("score",mScore); //pass score to Menu2
                    startActivity(intent);




                }
            }


        });
        //End of Button Listener1

        //Start of Button Listener2
        mButtonChoice2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //My logic for Button goes in here

                if (mButtonChoice2.getText() == mAnswer) {
                    mScore = mScore + 1;
                    updateScore(mScore);
                    updateQuestion();




                    //This line of code is optional...
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Oh... wrong your score is 0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, Menu2.class);
                    intent.putExtra("score",mScore); //pass score to Menu2
                    startActivity(intent);




                }
            }


        });
        //End of Button Listener2

        //Start of Button Listener3
        mButtonChoice3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //My logic for Button goes in here

                if (mButtonChoice3.getText() == mAnswer) {
                    mScore = mScore + 1;
                    updateScore(mScore);
                    updateQuestion();




                    //This line of code is optional...
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Come on, that was not so hard...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, Menu2.class);
                    intent.putExtra("score",mScore); //pass score to Menu2
                    startActivity(intent);




                }
            }


        });
        //End of Button Listener3

    }


    private void updateQuestion() {
    //If the max. number of questions is reached, menu2 will be open if not  
    //a  new quiz selection appears
    if (mQuestionNumber < mQuestionLibrary.getLength()) {

    mQuestionView.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getQuestion(mQuestionNumber));

    mButtonChoice1.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice1(mQuestionNumber));

    mButtonChoice2.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice2(mQuestionNumber));

    mButtonChoice3.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice3(mQuestionNumber));

        mAnswer = mQuestionLibrary.getCorrectAnswer(mQuestionNumber);
        mQuestionNumber++;
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Last Question! You are very intelligent!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, Menu2.class);
        intent.putExtra("score",mScore); //pass score to Menu2
        startActivity(intent);


    }

}

private void updateScore ( int point){
    mScoreView.setText("" + mScore);
    //Shared preferences = a variabe (mScore) gets saved and call up in another activity
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("mypref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt("currentscore", mScore);
    editor.apply();
}

    @Override //Makes that the "Burger" Item, shows the Drawer if someone clicks on the simbol
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item){
        if (mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Menu 2:

```
      public class Menu2 extends AppCompatActivity {




private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout2;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;
private Toolbar mToolbar;
private Button popup;
private PopupWindow popupWindow;private LayoutInflater layoutInflater; //Alows to add a new layout in our window



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu2);

    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("mypref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int applyView =sharedpreferences.getInt("currentscore",0);
     TextView txtScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textScore2);
     TextView txtHighScore = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textHighScore);
     ImageView imgTrophyView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.trophy1);
     ImageView imgTrophyView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.trophy2);
     Button bttPOPUP =(Button)findViewById(R.id.enablePOPUP);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int mScore = intent.getIntExtra ("score",0);
    txtScore.setText("Your score is: " + mScore);




    SharedPreferences mypref =getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    int highScore = mypref.getInt("highScore", 0);
    if (highScore>= mScore)
        txtHighScore.setText("High score: " + highScore);


    else{
        txtHighScore.setText("New highscore: " + mScore);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mypref.edit();
        editor.putInt("highScore",mScore);
        editor.apply();

    }

    if (applyView >=10) {
        imgTrophyView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        bttPOPUP.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
        if (applyView >= 20){
            imgTrophyView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }


    popup = (Button)findViewById(R.id.enablePOPUP);
    popup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            layoutInflater =(LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup)layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_menu2_1,null);
            popupWindow = new PopupWindow(container,1000,980,true); //400,400=popUp size, true = makes that we can close the pop up by simply click out of the window
            popupWindow.showAtLocation(mDrawerLayout2, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            mDrawerLayout2.setAlpha((float) 0.1);

            container.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){

                @Override

                        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent  ){
                        mDrawerLayout2.setAlpha((float) 1);
                              popupWindow.dismiss();

                        return true;

                }

            });


            popupWindow.setOnDismissListener(new PopupWindow.OnDismissListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDismiss() {
                    mDrawerLayout2.setAlpha((float) 1);
                    popupWindow.dismiss();

                }
            });
        }
    });





    mToolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.nav_action);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    mDrawerLayout2 = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout2);

    mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout2, R.string.open, R.string.close);
    mDrawerLayout2.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
    mToggle.syncState();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    NavigationView mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(nv2);
    mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem){
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
                case(R.id.nav_home2):
                    Intent accountActivity2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),QuizActivity.class);
                    startActivity(accountActivity2);

            }
            return true;
        }
    });}

            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Menu2.this, QuizActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

}




@Override //Makes that the "Burger" Item, shows the Drawer if someone clicks on the simbol
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

in your `updateScore` you are saving the data no matter what score is, so you delete the old value and change it with the new one, so you need to read the old score and compare it with the mScore like this :

```
SharedPreferences mypref =getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
int highScore = mypref.getInt("highScore", 0);
if(mScore> highScore){
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mypref.edit();
    editor.putInt("currentscore", mScore);
    editor.apply();
}
```

Comment: Hello! Where do I have to insert this?

Comment: I insert it under updateScore but now the picture even do not appear...

Comment: Hello his works perfectly only that If i reach for example the score 10  and directly after i reach a score of fx. 1 then it rest permanently..  I want that it appears already when the HIGHSCORE is "reached"

Answer (score 0):

That happens because you have the following code

```
if (applyView >=10) {
    imgTrophyView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    bttPOPUP.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
    if (applyView >= 20){
        imgTrophyView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}
```

That checks the "currentScore" so if the user find only 1 answer the second time he is playing it's going to be 1 so the image won't show.
I notice that you have a sharedPref for current score and you also pass it with intent. You also have another sharedPref? My suggestion is to only pass it with intent and then check if it's a highscore, then save it to sharedPref. And only have one sharedPref.

EDIT

Remove the code below from updateScore

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("mypref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putInt("currentscore", mScore);
editor.apply();
```

Then remove/edit all the shared pref code that you have in Menu 2 with something like this

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("mypref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

//first time high score
if (sharedPreferences.getInt("highScore", 0) == 0)
{
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt("highScore", mScore );
    editor.apply();
}
else
{
    int oldScore = sharedPreferences.getInt("highScore", 0);

    //new high score
    if (mScore  > oldScore)
    {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putInt("highScore", mScore );
        editor.apply();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello! Where do I have to insert this code Sir? In Menu2? and do I have to delete smething?

Comment: Yes you have to remove updateScore from your QuizActivity since you pass the score with an intent and then edit your sharedPref code in your other activity. Or change the apllyView in your Menu2 to be highScore

Comment: So I have to remove the update score in Quiz Activity and in Menu2 which code do I have to insert? I don`t know where to put in this code Sir

Comment: When I remove the update score, on the Buton listener on the part update score is the error cannot solve simbol..

Comment: Hello, I found a slution only that it do not work perfetly. Could you help me too? the answer is over yours from Oussema